# Glassfish and Java SOAP webservice

Tags: java, soap, glassfish

I have a simple SOAP Java project that I have a deployed to a local Glassfish 5 server.
The artifact is recognised by Glassfish as webservice but I do not see any wsdl link exposed and these are the links provided by Glassfish:

```
http://fullnames-macbook-pro.local:8080/service-1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

The link does not look good to me, and returns a 404 not found.

Below is the pom:

SOAP example
org.example
1.0-SNAPSHOT

4.0.0

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
<artifactId>service</artifactId>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548702/glassfish-v3-soap-existing-webservice-not-launching

Answer (score 1):

I was missing an important plugin to generate the wsdl:

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsgen</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!--Optional-->
                        <!--Reads a JAX-WS service endpoint implementation class and generates all of the portable artifacts for a JAX-WS web service-->
                        <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <keep>true</keep>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```